# IAR EW new text editor file extensions

Tags: editor, iar

Recently I instal IAR EW for MSP430 v5.51.6. It has a new text editor. I open my project and what I see is that all file tabs in editor window is without extensions. I have global.c and global.h. In new editor tabs look the same. How to make extension to be visible?

Comment: Use "Folder properties" in Windows "Control panel" and make extensions of all files visible.